# Javascript: test single character is found in regex string

Tags: javascript, regex

I confess at the outset that I dislike and don't really understand regex properly. I want to check that a single character `ch` is one of a set of acceptable characters. I thought this should work, but it doesn't:

```
if (/aCcehIikmNnOoprSstxYy/.test(ch)) {
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: Your regex means you are expecting exactly the string `aCcehIikmNnOoprSstxYy`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this can be solved without regex:

```
var characters = "aCcehIikmNnOoprSstxYy";
var allowed    = characters.indexOf("C") != -1;

if (allowed) {
  // do something here
}
```

String.indexOf() returns -1 if character is not in string, otherwise positive number.

Comment: A much better solution. Indexof in this case is also much faster than regex. See a speed comparison here: http://jsperf.com/regexp-vs-indexof For example my Chrome 19's indexOf is about twice as fast as regex is.

Comment: I should add that if you prefer, this could also be made a one liner very easily. `if (​String("aCcehIikmNnOoprSstxYy").indexOf("C") != -1)​​​​​​​​ {`

Comment: String(...) is not necessary, it's legitimate to use directly: "aCcehIikmNnOoprSstxYy".indexOf("C")

Comment: Thanks, everyone. I used `if ("aCcehIikmNnOoprSstxYy".indexOf(ch) !== -1) {`

Answer (score 3):

you need to enclose the set of characters in [ ]:

```
if (/[aCcehIikmNnOoprSstxYy]/.test(ch)) {
```

Without that you are trying to match the whole string 'aCcehIikmNnOoprSstxYy'.